# Inferring function signatures for an object with string keys and function values in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I am trying to define an object with string keys and function values in TypeScript, and I want to ensure that the required function parameters are enforced when calling the functions. I also want to type the object with Record<string, StringReturningFunction> to ensure that the values of the object are functions that take in string arguments and return a string.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
type StringReturningFunction = (...args: string[]) => string;

type ConfigurationObject = Record<string, StringReturningFunction>;

const myConfiguration: ConfigurationObject = {
  functionName1: (str1: string) => `Function 1 called with ${str1}.`,
  functionName2: (str1: string, str2: string) => `Function 2 called with ${str1} and ${str2}.`,
};

const result1 = myConfiguration.functionName1('hello');
const result2 = myConfiguration.functionName2('hello', 'world');
const result3 = myConfiguration.functionName2('hello'); // Type error expected
```

Currently, TypeScript does not enforce the required function parameters when calling the functions. Is there a way to infer the function signatures, without explicitly defining the function signatures during object definition?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Typescript 4.9 or higher, the `satisfies` keyword should work nicely:

```
const myConfiguration = {
  functionName1: (str1: string) => `Function 1 called with ${str1}.`,
  functionName2: (str1: string, str2: string) => `Function 2 called with ${str1} and ${str2}.`,
  oops: (val: number) => false, // TS alerts us that this is incompatible with ConfigurationObject
} satisfies ConfigurationObject;

const result1 = myConfiguration.functionName1('hello');
const result2 = myConfiguration.functionName2('hello', 'world');
const result3 = myConfiguration.functionName2('hello'); // Type error correctly shown
```

The type for `myConfiguration` is going to be inferred, and so typescript will know exactly which functions exist and exactly which types they accept and return. But if any of the functions are incompatible with `ConfigurationObject`, such as the `oops` function i added, typescript will give you an error,

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwEoWAV3slqAYtsgMbCID2yUAvFABQB0LAhvKgM4BcUnCBANoBdAJR0AfHwFoA3AFgAUEtCQoAYWoAzRKlysK1APIAjAFYRydKJlKV4AEwA8-JGgA0sGRiy58aYjJDZAkFZUU7ZH4oAFsQTWQdPXgDKhp6AG8lKCgtEnI0gDlWGIgARl4GVwrpN1RxWikAA0CC6igyqFJWABseiAcoAHdEYAALKAASDOqAXyYm92zc-ODi0oAmSureVwJPVy3aggbm1uCoDa7e-sGR8amZhDLZqFZkQenD%20cXlykowDxGAA3Xq8ZDYGImCDwU65XqcCCeAD0yKgABUYG9%20vBgJwoNh8eMDFBxoh8eSoCg7DEwKkTP1hqMJgkkvpgqYLOQlK9OKlODoIPjWbp2WlOZZgGElJFovAhdgesBOvQ4iLkqlqEw8kEiiVygwAORjCB9SiG0RhWXAKDyziK4BXVXxbSilLBbWrPWbI0ms2GzyGob2HoOC1W6hyhVKgDM1jVro1Hp1bWQ6wgG19pp65stUFRGPA0Bh8HsXXs8vIPRAfDGlCGyCUQA)

Comment: Thanks! This works as expected. Great that TypeScript offers the `satisfied` keyword now!